# Multiple rules for a given sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations

Imagine we are given a sequence of numbers, say $1$, $1$, $9$, $25$, and we want to find a rule for such sequence. For example, the formula $$x_n = (2n-1)^2$$
for $n=0,1,2,3$ gives the desired results. However, I have the hunch that we could, in principle, be able find another formula whose first four outputs are these same numbers. In fact, something tells me that given a finite sequence of numbers there must be an infinite number of formulas, however complicated they may be, giving as a result such sequence. Of course, if the given sequence has infinite terms, then there's no ambiguity and the only solution for this sequence must be a single formula.

Is there any theorem relating these facts? Is my intuition right or I am missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The catch is that we cannot write down an infinite sequence , unless we know the pattern and can then write "$\cdots$" at some point , or we have a description (for example "the prime numbers"). Moreover, a totally different looking formula might produce the same infinite sequence. The formulas are then in fact equivalent, but we have to specify what is meant with "unique" to avoid this issue.

Comment: For finite number of values there are infinite many formulas to produce the desired result. For example zero can be obtained in infinite number of ways and then added to your formula for $x_n$

Comment: Given $k$ values, there is $1$ and only $1$ polynome with degree $k-1$ that gives the desired result. And infinite number of polynomes with degree higher than $k-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Any sequence of $n$ terms can be modelled by a polynomial of degree $n−1$, with which we can compute succesive terms. Usually an interpolating polynomial is used.

Comment: The question is about the uniqueness of a formula if a sequence with IFINITE many entries is given.

Comment: I was replying to the finite case: "something tells me that given a finite sequence of numbers there must be an infinite number of formulas, however complicated they may be, giving as a result such sequence". There is an infinite number of interpolating polynomials for a given finite sequence.

Comment: If we have the sequence $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,\cdots$, we can of course interpolate but a reasonable guess would be "the prime numbers" in this case. Or if we have $2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,\cdots$ , we would guess $2^n$ rather than any polynomial. So, without context, we have no reason to choose the polynomial interpolation. What is true is that the polynomial interpolation shows that such problems are ill-posted without context, but the ill-posted character was already mentioned in the question.

Comment: You're right. Interpolation "works" best for finite sequences only. The problem with infinite sequences is that we can define them only by stating a rule i.e. recursion, which makes them unique up to the initial terms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one: $x_0=1$ and $x_n=n^4-10n^3+39n^2-54n+25$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}.$

Also you can construct many formulas as you need using [Lagrange interpolation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivprajubzYAhWl5YMKHeHjBTIQFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLagrange_polynomial&usg=AOvVaw0RiAvsjM48xLbTbp9p7Ijm) (or some other interpolation method) for any given sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is an important problem in philosophy of science called underdetermination of theory by data. You can read more about it [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination/)