# How do you know how many formulas or rules there are that fit a given sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Given any sequence, is there a limit to the number of unique solutions that sequence may have?

I'm also not sure in a sense whether uniqueness is even possible if you have two formulas which both provide the same output at each step for an infinite sequence of numbers. In such a case, are the two formulas then by definition "the same", I'm not sure.

For example if given the sequence: 1, 3, ....
 And asked what comes next.

You might say 5 (2n-1) or you might say 9 (3^(n-1)), both being equally valid. Clearly, if we add a 3rd value 1,3,5 we rule out the *3 formula as a possibility. This implies at least that as we're given more values in a sequence, the number of valid formulas that predict it is limited.

I'm also not sure in a sense whether uniqueness is even possible if you have two formulas which both provide the same output at each step for an infinite sequence of numbers. In such a case, are the two formulas then by definition "the same", I'm not sure.

This leads to the sub-question: "is the number of solutions to a sequence (described arbitrarily as x1,x2,x3) upper bounded by the number of solutions to (x1,x2,) where the next value is unknown and lower bounded by (x1,x2,x3,x4) (since the 4 term case is just a further constrained extension of the 3 term one)?

I have a few other questions based on the answers to the above ones, but this is my first time asking a question on stack, and I feel like it's poor form to ask multiple in a single post, so if you have an answer to one or some - just do what you can.

I saw a similar question here [Multiple rules for a given sequence of numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590571/multiple-rules-for-a-given-sequence-of-numbers), which at least answers the issue of (in some cases) there being as many solutions as desired for a *finite* sequence but I don't think it captures everything. Forgive my incompetence if otherwise

Comment: How do you define a rule? Do you mean a function? If a function is what you mean by a rule, yes, there are infinitely many. However, depending on the sequence, there might not be a closed form for the majority of the functions.

Comment: I think so. Just any formula that would predict the sequence. Could be recursive or general.

Comment: Logical algorithm? What does that mean?

Comment: That was unhelpful wording on my part. To be honest I'm not sure if the scope of my question is too wide, as I'm not too knowledgeable on the topic. Like you could describe a sequence with a polynomial but then you could also do it arithmetically or recursively. Do these need to be considered separately?

Comment: There's no guarantee on a polynomial fitting infinitely many points. I don't know what you mean by recursively or arithmetically.

Comment: You can define a sequence recursively. As in, define term n as a function of the previous terms. For example, 1,3,9. can be expressed by t(n) = t(n-1) *3.

Comment: Then the answer is again no, unless you allow for infinite formulas, since there are countably many formulas and uncountably many infinite sequences.

Comment: What do you mean by allowing for infinite formulas? Where did you get that there are countable many formulas from? Also, there are other parts to the post, are you able to help with them?

Comment: They are unanswerable because you haven't precisely defined the terms you are using. I know this sounds pedantic, but you can't do math without being precise, which you are not.

Comment: Is there at least a precise rewording of one of my questions you could hazard? If not that's okay, thanks for trying

Comment: no, because the answers are fully dependent on how you define the terms. I don't really think there's a good way to define the terms you are using (I tried above, but clearly that's not what you meant).